Can't book on Cathay Pacific because it needs "Government Approval"
While planning for end of year vacations, I found a very good set of flights on Google Flights to go from HND to DPS via HKG with CX. However, after confirming the fare, I get the following quite unhelpful error page:

I then tried on a different browser, and also on a different computer, but I got the same results.
I thought this was because I went through Google Flights. So instead I try to find the same flight directly from CX's website, but I can't find the exact flights. Maybe that is because the routing includes a 19 hour layover in HKG. I only found routings with much shorter layovers (but much more expensive).
After trying a couple of times and getting the same result, I tried calling CX to book over the phone. They found the routing I asked for, but told me I cannot book because "this routing and dates requires government approval". They didn't explain what this meant, or even which government approval is required.
Notice that up to this point, I haven't given my name, nationality or other personal details. This is an issue with the routing/dates, not anything specific to me (I hope).
I've booked dozens, if not more than one hundred flights in my lifetime, and this is the first time I hear about government approval required for booking a flight.
Does anybody know what this issue is, how to resolve it, or how to avoid this issue?
It seems like Expedia and Flight Network show me the route and allow me to purchase it, but I don't think it's a very good idea to do so.
Update
Cathay's website continues giving issues. Even if I start a search directly from Cathay's website, and after giving pax details and payment information, at the very last step, the website shows a blank page.
That said, I tried the same route today, and now I do get a real error message. It's not really helpful anyways though:

If you're interested in the details, this is the routing I was trying to do:

Book as return flight, not multi-city
Depart Dec 23 2024

CX 543 HND-HKG 10:10 14:30
(19:30 layover in HKG)
CX 785 HKG-DPS 10:00+1 15:10+1


Return Dec 30 2024

CX 784 DPS-HKG 16:10 21:20
(19:05 layover in HKG)
CX 542 HKG-HND 16:25+1 21:15+1


2 adults 2 children
Fares according to Google Flights:

378960 JPY on Cathay Pacific - Get error message; can't book
378960 JPY on Expedia - Seems fine
352402 JPY on Flightnetwork - Seems fine



I also searched all four flights on Flightaware, and all of them have been operating for at least last week -- none of these seem to be new flights with tentative schedules, which seem to be the ones most affected by "government approval".
Regardless, since these flights don't seem to be bookable, and I think it's too risky to try to book on a third party website, I changed my plans and will be going to a completely different destination with a different airline.

For a flight route from Tokyo to Bali, through Hong Kong may presently need a special government approval.

@MarkJohnson Can you please elaborate? Is this something that's documented anywhere?

The flight route may be flying over (or near) Taiwan airspace.

@MarkJohnson: You raise more questions than resolve them. Do you have any sources for your comments?

Try everyday new sources, such as: China launches military drills surrounding Taiwan - BBC News

@MarkJohnson: Cathay is still offering TYO-HKG and HKG-DPS. If the flight itself was at risk, they wouldn't say it "needs approval", but rather cancel it outright. Do you have any sources as to how CX's flights to TYO or DPS are affected by the geopolitical situation between China and Taiwan?

@PandaPajama: this is indeed weird and IMO unlikely to be related "government approval". I'm guessing each individual leg is operating anyway (and as such approved) and the government doesn't care about how the airline combines legs into itineraries. Can you add the exact dates to your question. It would help with a deep dive. Chances are the problem is in CX's auto-pricing system and the deep discount for the long layover needs to be approved by someone in CX (but not the government).

My guess is that somebody, likely Japan, has imposed a sixth freedom quota on CX. So it is an issue of government market approval of that specific origin and destination and carrier in that time period.

@user71659: if that's the case, why would you be able to buy it from Expedia?

@user71659 That was my thought as well, but the sixth freedom is rarely regulated, contrary to the fifth. And it seems weird they would allow it on some flight combinations but not others.

Is the HKG layover overnight or the same day? Also, what happens if you try "multi-city" rather than return flight? Note: I don't actually recommend booking it as multi-city because that can have an effect on the conditions in case of disruption, on luggage check-through, and on price, but just to see if they have the same error in that situation or not.

@Hilmar Because presumably Expedia are taking on the risk that it might not get approved?

@Hilmar Nobody's bought it from Expedia. It could error out when Expedia actually tries to get it ticketed.

In the context of flights, "[subject to] government approval" means that an airline has announced that it intends to fly a certain route, but it has not received the necessary approvals from both sides to be able to actually commence flying.  See What does Flight Pending Government Approval mean? for more detail.
Since approvals are rarely rejected, airlines can and do sometimes start taking bookings for these flights before the approval comes through.  However, in your specific case, this is completely nonsensical as a reason not to allow you to book this specific itinerary: as other answers have pointed out, the flights operate already so obviously the necessary approvals have been granted, and even the specific itinerary can be booked on different websites, meaning it's not a case of you hitting some obscure seat cap or expiry date in the approval etc.
For what it's worth, it's not unknown of for official websites to struggle with booking flights you can get elsewhere, especially if there's a long layover involved, I had very similar issues with China Airlines last year.  I am surprised even their call center couldn't make the booking for you though.

Thanks for your reply. I checked all four flights on flightaware, and they have been operating without issue. They don't seem to be new routes. I added more details on my question if you're interested.

This appears to be a bug on the CX's own website.
I reproduced the problems using the date of Feb 7 to Feb 12 with the flights CX543/CX785 outbound and CX784/CX548 inbound.
I have verified

The itinerary errors out on CX website
The itinerary is bookable on Booking.com without problem
You can buy the exact same flights on CX website as two separate round trip tickets.

That means there is nothing wrong with the flights or the specific itinerary themselves.

"this routing and dates requires government approval"

That seems highly unlikely. What governmental approval would be required for CX to sell on their own website one of their own products that's readily available through a different vendor already? Chances are the agent had no clue what the problem was.
Your options:

Wait a few days and try again
Call again and be more persistent. "How come I can book this on Expedia?" or "I prefer booking with you instead of Expedia. How do you suggest I proceed. Why can I buy your ticket from Expedia but not from you?"
Look at alternatives. For the dates I looked at, this was around US$670. There were plenty of other options in this price range including other options from CX


Note that being shown and apparently bookable on Booking or Expedia does not mean it actually is. Unless you actually book and get a confirmed and ticket booking, you don't know if it won't give an error at the time you actually try to book it and the booking request is sent to CX (I suppose you didn't really book the flight!).

Understood but in this case I got to the point where the collected the payment info. It is very rare that something goes wrong after this. Typically you get kicked out when they price the ticket for real.

Thanks a lot. You actually tried the exact same flights I was trying. I added more details, but I ended up changing my plans entirely and choosing a different destination with a different airline. Also, the agent was clearly working from a script, the conversation wasn't really going anywhere.

The error message is a placeholder for the actual error message. Looks like there is a bug on the booking website's translation tables that got hit by your search (maybe a missing translation string).
Yes, the message is not useful to you but an indication for the people maintaining the site where to look for the problem. Ideally end users should never see such messages, and a generic "something went wrong, please contact XXXXX and notify them of this error" should be displayed instead.
Mark already answered the question about the booking needing government approval: the flight route probably takes it over a currently very hot area where war may break out at any moment. It's not your booking per se that needs approval most likely but the entire flight (unless the airline decides to reroute it, which they may end up doing). This fact may well be the reason for the cryptic error message on the 3rd party booking site, such rare things are easy to forget to implement in translation tables and even easier to be tested for when the software is going through quality control.

From what I'm reading, this kind of stuff is more related to airport slots rather than geopolitical issues, and one of the four flights is probably still pending approval at any of the related airports. I seriously doubt this is a geopolitical issue like Mark is asserting.

@PandaPajama for a well established route like that I doubt it. Is it possible? Sure. But afaik Cathay has been flying to Bali and Tokyo Haneda for years. And of course Hong Kong is their home base.

even easier to be tested for when the software is going through quality control, I found this part hard to parse.  I assume you mean even easier to forget but as formulated it reads like it's easy to test it.

That answer can't be right. This would affect every flight between HKG and Japan and CX is flying a lot of those every day. CX DOES operate and sell HND<->DPS itineraries on their website, just not the combo the OP wants.

@Hilmar more likely it affects the leg from Hong Kong to Bali.

@jwenting:  My argument still stands. CX operates a daily flight from HKG to DPS. The exact itinerary can be booked on Expedia or Booking.com without issues (I checked) . If there is really any government approval missing (which I highly doubt) it cannot be about the flights or even the itinerary but only about what CX can sell on their own website. That seems a silly assumption.

@Hilmar no, your argument is invalid. In cases like this EVERY SINGLE overflight needs to be separately approved, or at the very least checked against rapidly changing airspace closures. That's the problem with operating in a volatile region. What happens if you ignore such precautions is MH-17.

@jwenting: You CAN book the exact flights as two separate round trips on CXs website. You CAN book the exact  itinerary the OP wants on Expedia or Book. That means the flights are already approved. The only thing that's not working is booking the combo itinerary on CX's website. Its hard to see what government approval would be require to sell an EXISTING itinerary with EXISTING flights on their website, unless the government is actively interested in steering business to Expedia etc

@Hilmar I think Japan imposed a sixth freedom quota or limitation on CX on that route. That would explain why the flights cannot be combined.

@user71659. CX offers HND<->DPS on the dates I checked. Just not the combo the OP wants. So whatever the limitations are, they would have to be based on price and/or layover etc but not on the route itself.
